# Send values to $_GET using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm using a PHP script that is waiting for two values through $_GET.

I'm trying to pass those 2 values using jQuery and that's where I'm not too good at.

Here's the code I've got.

Can somebody point me in the right direction ? Thanks !

```
function xrate(id,rating){  

   $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_xrate.php?id="+id+"&rate="+rating,
      global: false,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "text",
      async:false,
      success: function(){
         alert('Bravo!');
      }
   });

}
```

*(actual code copied from the comments)*

```
function xrate(id,rating){ 
    var oDate = new Date(); 
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
    $.ajaxSetup({ 
        scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" 
    }); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_xrate.php?timestamp='+oDate.getMilliseconds(), 
        dataType: 'html', 
        data: {itemid:id, keyrate:rating}, 
        cache: false, 
        type: "GET", 
        success : function(dataReturn){ 
            alert(dataReturn); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: And what exactly is happening? Do you have a problem? My guess would be problems with parameter encoding (and `async:false` is a bad idea).

Comment: My code is actually this : 

`function xrate(id,rating){  
  
 var oDate = new Date();
  $.ajaxSetup({
      cache: false
  });
  
  $.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" });
  
  $.ajax({ 
    url: 'ajax_xrate.php?timestamp='+oDate.getMilliseconds(),
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {itemid:id,keyrate:rating},
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    success : function(dataReturn){
      alert(dataReturn);
    }
     });

}`
On this other side, I'm echoing the values with 
`$print_r($_GET);`

But I don't get anything echoed ...

Comment: Maybe because it should `print_r($_GET)` (without `$`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function xrate(id,rating){  

   $.ajax({
      url: "ajax_xrate.php",
      data: {
          id: id,
          rate:rating
      },
      type: "GET",
      success: function(){
         alert('Bravo!');
      }
   });

}
```

Comment: Hi hsz, thanks for your quick answer !!  Although I'm pretty sure your answer is correct, I can't seem to be able to make it work.

How should I get the values in the PHP script ?

$id_value = $_GET['id'];
$rate_value = $GET['rate'];

Would it be correct ?  Also, how can I use "echos" in my PHP script to help be debug, and see the results appear in the webpage ?

Comment: @user641747: To get the values is correct that you mentioned. To debug in webpage, although I don't recommend it. You use `success: function(text){ // use the text parameter to see any reporting }`

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
function xrate(id,rating){  

   $.get("ajax_xrate.php",
      {
          'id': id,
          'rate': rating
      }, 
     function(){
       alert('Bravo!')
     }
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jquery.ajax work like this

jQuery.ajax({
   url:'you_ur',
   type:'GET'  or 'POST',
   data:{prop1:value1},  // name value pair of props waiting on server
   //etc etc here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
function xrate(id,rating){  

   $.ajax({
          url: "ajax_xrate.php",
          data: "id="+id+"&rate="+rating,
          async:false,
          success: function(){
             alert('Bravo!');
          }
   });

}
```

You don't need set parameters like `type = 'get'` because they are already default. Every parameters shall be inputed in the `data:` either in string form(like the one above) or object form(`{id: '45', rate: 'something'}`). Async is also true on default in case you didn't know